# Python: Edit CSV file - Join two rows and change name of columns

Tags: python, csv, concatenation, row, weka

I am doing a project with Python in which I have to use Weka and so I have to use arff files that I can get from csv's that I am creating that contain molecular descriptors.

Something like this:

```
                Name      nAcid    ALogP  ...     WPOL   XLogP  Zagreb
0         AUTOGEN_bumex      1  -1.4399   ...     37.0   1.220   124.0
1     AUTOGEN_cenestin       0   0.3269   ...     44.0   0.247   140.0
2     AUTOGEN_clozapine      0   1.6380   ...     41.0   2.583   126.0
3        AUTOGEN_diovan      3   0.5202   ...     49.0   4.409   160.0
4        AUTOGEN_evista      0   0.7973   ...     54.0   2.720   182.0
5    AUTOGEN_folic acid      2  -3.5377   ...     48.0  -3.972   162.0
6        AUTOGEN_forteo      5 -35.1594   ...    430.0 -13.601  1374.0
7   AUTOGEN_hydroxyzine      0   2.2387   ...     37.0   0.800   128.0
8        AUTOGEN_nexium      0  -0.5219   ...     39.0  -0.882   126.0
9         AUTOGEN_paxil      0  -0.2902   ...     35.0   2.271   128.0
10    AUTOGEN_potassium      0      NaN   ...      0.0   0.000     0.0
11   AUTOGEN_prednisone      0  -0.7488   ...     59.0   0.608   154.0
12      AUTOGEN_provera      0   0.5736   ...     62.0   4.279   164.0
13   AUTOGEN_cimetidine      0   0.5736   ...     62.0   4.279   164.0
14   AUTOGEN_irinotecan      0   0.5736   ...     62.0   4.279   164.0`
```

I need to go through a list of known interactions between this compounds and if I find some interaction (for example between cimetidine and irinotecan) I have to append to create a new row in which has 'cimetidine' row and 'irinotecan' row in front of it, like this:

```
              Name  nAcid    ALogP   ...     WPOL   XLogP  Zagreb  Name2  nAcid2    ALogP2   ...     WPOL2   XLogP2  Zagreb2
AUTOGEN_cimetidine      0   0.5736   ...     62.0   4.279   164.0  AUTOGEN_irinotecan      0   0.5736   ...     62.0   4.279   164.0
```

And if I don't find any interaction for that givin compound I just have a line with the compound and the properties and then the columns that were meant for the properties of the second compound would just be blank or 0.

I just don't know how can I do this, if someone could help me that would be great! :)

Comment: What you have so far?

Comment: I have been trying with pandas and I can create new columns and give them a certain value with "for column in columns: df[column + '_interaction'] = 'value'"
But I don't know how to get values from other columns and put them in the new columns that I created.